# get value of XML node, ignoring its children's values

Tags: xml, scala

I have an XML file that looks like this

```
<a>
  hello
  <b>
    world
  </b>
</a>
```

I would like to use **Scala** to extract just `a`'s value, without including any of its children (i.e. without including `b`'s value). Currently, if `a` is a `scala.xml.Node`, then `a.text` returns `helloworld`. What do I type if I just want `hello`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the text node `hello` and the element node `<b>world</b>` are children of a. If you want to get just the text nodes, you can use the normal collection methods:

```
val x = <a>Hello<b>world</b></a>
x.child.collect {
  case t: xml.Text ⇒ t.toString
}.mkString // "hello"
```